# What is optimal way for connect JSON in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

**I have JSON like**:

```
   { 
     items:[],
     errors:[],
     foundItems:9
   }
```

At one place to me need "items", at another place - "errors".

I created a new **interface** and a new class and returned that class. But it's not convenient because I have internal arrays.
I recently saw a new way to get JSON via **.map** *(mapping)* and now I want to understand which one is more optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you receive this JSON from backend, what you need to do is only create an `interface` for it, and that's it.

and then when you want to get this data, you'll do something like that:

`this.http.get<YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME>('/items).subscribe(...);`

this is an example for HTTP get request, and the data that you expect to get is typed by your interface.

I don't know exactly what do you mean by `map` but maybe you meant to rxjs operator - map.
this operator is used to map the data for async request such as HTTP request but it's not a replacement of creating an interface

read about this operator [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map)